# Trying to find out prime numbers using for loop but my code is not working, why?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class forLoopPrimeNumberSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter begining value: ");
        int beginingValue = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter ending value: ");
        int endingValue = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Prime number between " + beginingValue+ " to "+ endingValue);
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = beginingValue; i<= endingValue; i++){
            if(i <=1){
                continue;
            }
            boolean ifPrime = true;
            for( int k = 2; k <= i ; k++){
             //if i write the above line like this than i get the expected result for( int k = 
                    if(i % k == 0){
                    ifPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(ifPrime){
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Number count: " +counter);

    }
```

Maybe there are many different ways to solve this problem but as a beginner, I try to implement what I have learned so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for( int k = 2; k <= i ; k++)
```

Because of this condition: `k <= i` You're checking `k` as a factor of `i` when `k` is equal to `i`. So you'll always find a factor, even if `i` is prime.

Change the condition to `k < i`. Or if you want your code to be a little more efficient, stop when `k` is greater than the square root of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, your loop condition is `k <= i`. This will make it so that when you get to the last iteration of the loop, you check "is i divisible by i?", which of course will yield a result of a composite number. What you want to do is check all of the numbers less than i, or to be more precise less than the square root of k, to really check the primality of the number. Your loop will then become like so.

```
boolean ifPrime = true;
for(int k = 2; k <= Math.sqrt(i); k++) {
    if(i % k == 0) {
        ifPrime = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, for this type of algorithm where you have to find all of the prime numbers in a certain range, something like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm will work much better and will be faster.